# UIBarButtonItem tintColor issue while setting bold text on in accessibility

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

UIBarButtonItem tintColor is not getting change after setting Bold Text On in Settings -> Display & Brightness -> Bold Text.
i am facing this issue in iOS 11 & 12 both. haven't checked in previous versions.

The same question is already asked in apple developer forum but i didn't find any answer there.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89337

if some one have any work around to this please suggest me.

Comment: Did you tried do it programmatically ?

Comment: yes, i am setting tintColor programmatically and its working fine when the Bold Text is disabled

Comment: can you show us the code that you have??

Comment: btn.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it programmatically using `NSAttributedString`, I have never done it trough the storyboard, but programmatically using array of `[NSAttributedString.Key.font: .systemFontOfSize(size: 25), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: .blue]`, etc., works like a charm.

Comment: actually i have image inside the UIBarButtonItem. thats why i need to set tintColor

Answer (score 0):

One method that works for me is changing the Global Tint option on the storyboard, of course this is not the perfect solution.

[image]